Azure function app logs stop outputting to app insights inside new thread
I have a C# function app which runs a very long operation, and a pipeline which invokes it with the AzureFunction@1 task. The way to use this task is to start the function actual work in a new thread, immediately returning a response to the pipeline that the function has started working, which then start the pipeline countdown.
The first implementation of the function used a single thread and then everything worked as expected, at least log wise. After converting the function to do its job in a new thread (using Task.Run(()=> ... ), what happens is that at first I see some logs from the new thread in app insights (logged with an ILogger), but after 3 or 4 entries, it just stops and I have no idea if the function is running or not (The pipeline itself keeps running, waiting for a response).
Is there something needed to be changed with logging when writing in a new thread? Something else that you think can affect it?
EDIT: Seems like using Console.Writeline DOES work. Don't know if it helps identifying the issue
A pseudo code of my code to demonstrate what I'm doing:
public MyWorkingClass(ILogger log)
{
_logger = log;
}
public string Run()
{
  //this is not blocking so the return would be called immediately 
  Task.Run(() =>
  {
    _logger.LogInformation("starting");
    ... do more stuff ..
  }
  return "Starting task";
}


I don't think the azure function hosting model supports this way of working. In my mind the runtime executes the function, returns a response and then the process is halted. I am not sure a newly created thread will survive the runtime execution. Have you check whether your thread runs all the way to the end?

But even Microsoft documentation says I need to open a new thread in order to work with AzureFunction@1 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/azure-function-v1?view=azure-pipelines#example-of-an-azure-function-that-uses-the-callback-completion-mode

I see. Didn't know. Question: are you running on a consumption plan and how long is very long? More than say 5 minutes?

The plan is Premium v2 so it may even have an unbounded run in time. It can take even hours. For now I set the function timeout to 2 hours

Is the logger created inside the Task.Run or is it passed using dependency injection? Can you post the code?

The ILogger is passed with DI and the same instance is being used to log also inside the context of the new thread inside Thread.Run. I'm currently also trying to see if using Console.Writeline somehow works

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think the use of Thread.Sleep in the linked example is a bit of a red herring. It's just being used to simulate a long-running operation. Also; note that they given an example of 70 seconds as "long running", which is well within the typical runtime limit of an Azure Function. If your Function takes several minutes then you would be outside of that. And finally, there's rarely a need to use Threads directly, as Task will achieve it with much less complexity. Perhaps you could share your code so we could help further? Thanks.

@AndrewB I edited with some pseudo code of what I'm doing. A thread is a must according to the documentation since only then does the AzureFunction@1 task starts working

I think people do need to see more of your code to help you, but maybe if I write an answer explaining how the Microsoft example is working then it'll help you figure out your problem?

I hope so..  My guess is that since I need to return a response right away which effectively ends the function's run (except for the new thread), some context is lost somewhere inside ILogger.. Will be glad to see if you know what could it be.

What I eventually did was creating my own ILogger inside the new thread, using the same configurations as in my host.json file using this method:
internal static ILogger GetILogger(string loggerName)
{
 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                        .AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                        .Build();

  using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
  {            
      builder.AddConfiguration(configuration.GetSection("logging"));
      builder.AddConsole();
  });

  var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(loggerName);
  return logger;
}

This method is call at the beginning of the Task.Run scope and the returned logger works perfectly, including logging to app insight.
